# Vmware Workstation Development Server on Laptop

Tags: networking, web-development, vmware-workstation

I'm running an Ubuntu guest OS on my Windows 7 laptop. Currently, I have it set up for bridged networking.

The guest is os is configured for a static ip of 192.168.1.115, which depending on the network I'm connected to, may not be available. When I want to view my development work I hit that up in my web browser.

I'm really looking for the following scenario:

1) My guest OS ip address stays constant.
2) I can access my guest os even if I don't have an internet connection, or a lan/router.
3) I can share files with my guest/host.

How does one accomplish this using VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [host only network adapter](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) to your virtual machine and assign a fixed IP to that interface.  That will give your VM and host machine there own private network where they can have fixed IP addresses and it will work regardless of any external network connection.

You will still keep your exiting bridged connection for Internet access; you VM will have two network adapters - one for the internal host only net work and one for the bridged network.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Guest config to NAT. Then it'll never have to change IP as it will always be on your laptop's private NAT network and it won't matter if the laptop is on a LAN or not. When your laptop has internet connection, the guest will too.

I should mention, though, that your laptop (the host) will be the only one that can browse sites on your guest (due to the nature of the NAT).